# Synchronize statusbar hide with toolbar

Tags: android, synchronization, android-animation, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

I've been trying to hide the toolbar and the statusbar together in a image Viewpager Activity. 
I tried to create a translate animation on the toolbar and hide the statusbar on animation start callback. Although the statusbar and toolbar hide, the animation looks as though the statusbar and toolbar are different layouts, This is not desirable as I've set the toolbar and statusbar transparency to match as though they're a single layout.

[image: toolbar and statusbar color matching]

How can I set the toolbar to hide the same way as the statusbar in terms of speed and interpolation?